# CCActionManager sharedManager is deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

I am working on cocos2d 2.x. Please let me know what is the replacement of below statement because shared manager is deprecated.?

```
  [[CCActionManager sharedManager] resumeTarget:sprite];
```

Comment: check ccDeprecated files

Answer (score 0):

its simple:

```
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] resumeTarget: sprite];
```